# python beginner - building list of couple with a group constraints

Tags: python

To begin, I have this list *(suggested in the exercise)*:

```
Members = [('Tessa','G1'),('Evan','G2'),('Tom','G3'),
('Mia','G3'),('Claire','G3'),('Billie','G4'),('Adrian',
'G2'),('Maddie','G1'),('Lewis','G1'),('Tony','G2'),('Joyce',
'G1'),('Julian','G5'),('Joshua','G2')('Warren','G3')]
```

At the end, I have to write a `randomMember(L)` function with parameter `L` which is the list `Members` defined above to make **pairs of two people** with the **following constraint**:

Two members of the same group `(G1, G2,  ...)` cannot meet each other.

For example, using the list `Members`, `"Tessa"` and `"Lewis"` cannot meet each other.

So, I have already written this (the base code has been provided, so the location of the loops should not be changed)

```
def randomMember(L):
    n = len(L)
    Perm = permutation(n)
    while checkConstrainst(Perm,random(L)) == False:
        Perm = permutation(n)
    LCouples=[]
    for k in range (n):
        LCouples.append((L[k],L[Perm[k]]))
    return LCouples
```

To explain more, `checkConstrainst` function takes two parameters. `Perm`, which is a list of integers and `L` is a list which represents a draw made in the `Members` list previously.

The purpose of this function is to ensure that 2 people are not from the same group. The input `L` looks like: `[(('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Lewis', 'G1')), (('Joshua', 'G2'), ('Billie', 'G4'))]`

```
def checkConstrainst(Perm,L):

    for i in range(len(Perm)):
        PeopleGroup_1, PeopleGroup_2 = L[i] 
        People1, Group1 = PeopleGroup_1
        People2, Group2 = PeopleGroup_2
        
        if Group1 == Group2:
            return False
    return True
```

I have to use permutation to make this working... I don't know how to use the list inputed to make sure `Perm` verify the constraint for the moment.

For the the list `[(('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Lewis', 'G1')), (('Joshua', 'G2'), ('Billie', 'G4'))]`, `checkConstraint` returns `False` and for the list `[(('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Joshua', 'G2')), (('Billie', 'G4'), ('Lewis', 'G1'))]` returns `True` because each couple is not from the same group.

The function `permutation` is just here to generate random integers.

Here is the code if you need:

```
def permutation(n):
    L=[]
    Perm=[]
    j=0
    for i in range(n):
        L.append(i)
    for k in range(n):
        alea = rd.randint(0,len(L)-1)
        j=L.pop(alea)
        Perm.append(j)
    return Perm
```

In `RandomMember`, you also have a `Random` function which takes the `Members` list as parameter. This function is making couple of people WITHOUT checking if they are from the same group (this is the goal of `RandomMember`). `Random` returns something like this : `[(('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Lewis', 'G1')), (('Joshua', 'G2'), ('Billie', 'G4'))]`.

So, my issue is that I've tested `checkConstrainst` and it works well.
But, in the `randomMember` function, while building the `LCouples` list, there is 2 peoples of  the same group in a couple...

Here if you need is the `random`, `derangement` and `isDerangement` function :

```
def isDerangement(Perm):
    for i in range(len(Perm)):
        if Perm[i]==i:
            return False
    return True

def derangement(n):
    Perm=permutation(n)
    while isDerangement(Perm)==False:
        Perm=permutation(n)
    return Perm

def random(L):
    n=len(L)
    Couples=[]
    D=derangement(n)

    for k in range(n):
        Couples.append((L[k],L[D[k]]))
    return Couples
```

And I don't understand where is my error despite several hours of looking...

For `randomMember(L)`, here is the basic code I should complete:

```
def randomMember(L):
    .............................................
    Perm =........................................
    while ......................................:
        Perm =....................................
    LCouples =[]
    for k in range (n):
    LCouples . append (.......................).
    return LCouples
```

Comment: which part of your code is the base code that can't be change? so I can try modifying the following part. Based on current code, I want to know is random(L) function related to Perm? If not, how can you related `LCouples.append((L[k],L[Perm[k]]))` to the result you do in checkConstraint?

Comment: Also, your example stated for `('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Lewis', 'G1')`, `checkConstraint` returns `True` but return `False` for `('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Joshua', 'G2')`. Your code likely doing the opposite.

Comment: @adamkwm you can edit the LCouples.append((L[k],L[Perm[k]])). I have edited my example statement, it's a mistake...

Comment: Cant this be as simple as creating a dictionary with `Gn` where `n` is the # 1,2,3,4,5... as keys and values = list of names from the members that match Gn? Then doing permutation of G1 with G2, G3, G4, G5.... and iterating thru it.

Comment: Since we are doing random pairing, can one member be paired with two people? Are there additional constraints that a member cannot be paired with anyone else in the final list?

Comment: So all checkConstraint(), permutation() and the random() need to exist? but can we change the code of these function?

Comment: I see that permutation(n) generates a random list of indexes from 0 thru len(Members). Good, we can use that. Then we have checkConstraint(). This is used to ensure that two members are not from the same group. And randomMember is the main function that needs to spit out the list of couples. Did I get it right?

Comment: What is random(L) ? How can you use random function this way. Shouldn't you use random.choice(L) instead?  random.choice() will returns a list with the randomly selected element from the specified sequence

Comment: should the definition of function `checkConstraints` have these two parameters? `Perm, L` ? The list of all indexes and a random member from the `Members` list? What do you expect the return to be? The random member will be part of one of the member. Isn't it. I dont understand the question at all.

Comment: @JoeFerndz You are right. checkConstraint() is used to ensure that two members are not from the same group and randomMember is the main function that give the list of couples.

Comment: What are the parameters for `checkConstraints`. The `Perm` list and `L`. Looking at your code `L` is supposed to be a pairing that you want to check if the constraint is OK. What does L and Perm have in common? What do I do with Perm if L is the paired item to check for constraint?

Comment: @GeneralHarrigton, let's make this very simple. What are the parts of the code that you MUST USE? 1. `randomMember`? I assume YES. 2. `permutation`? I assume YES. The question is to use the output from `permutation` which is a list and then pair those individuals with a random person from the `Members` list. When you do that, you must ensure that they are not part of the same group. Is this the summary of your question?

Comment: @JoeFerndz In `randomMember`, I have to use `checkConstraints()` with a while over this function. Then, use a for to build `LCouples`. Here is the basic code for `randomMember` I have to complete for your understaning (see original post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if your permutation() necessary? I find a way without using it.

```
import random
members = [
    ('Tessa','G1'),('Evan','G2'),('Tom','G3'),('Mia','G3'),('Claire','G3'),
    ('Billie','G4'), ('Adrian','G2'),('Maddie','G1'),('Lewis','G1'),
    ('Tony','G2'),('Joyce','G1'),('Julian','G5'),('Joshua','G2'),('Warren','G3')
]

# I don't know how your random(L) look like but this function should do the same
def random_couples(L):
    couples = []
    # shuffle the members
    rm = random.sample(L,len(L))
    for i in range(0, len(L), 2):
        couples.append((rm[i], rm[i+1]))
    # return couples of random members
    return couples

# no Perm needed
def check_constraint(L):
    for pg1, pg2 in L:
        if pg1[1] == pg2[1]:
            return False
    return True

def random_member(L):
    Lcouples = random_couples(L)
    while check_constraint(Lcouples) == False:
        Lcouples = random_couples(L)
    return Lcouples

print(random_member(members))
```

Output:

```
[(('Warren', 'G3'), ('Lewis', 'G1')), (('Maddie', 'G1'), ('Adrian', 'G2')), 
(('Evan', 'G2'), ('Tessa', 'G1')), (('Claire', 'G3'), ('Julian', 'G5')), 
(('Mia', 'G3'), ('Tony', 'G2')), (('Tom', 'G3'), ('Joyce', 'G1')), 
(('Joshua', 'G2'), ('Billie', 'G4'))]
```

```
[(('Warren', 'G3'), ('Joshua', 'G2')), (('Tony', 'G2'), ('Mia', 'G3')),
(('Billie', 'G4'), ('Tom', 'G3')), (('Claire', 'G3'), ('Lewis', 'G1')), 
(('Evan', 'G2'), ('Maddie', 'G1')), (('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Adrian', 'G2')), 
(('Joyce', 'G1'), ('Julian', 'G5'))]
```

```
[(('Lewis', 'G1'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Tony', 'G2'), ('Joyce', 'G1')), 
(('Adrian', 'G2'), ('Tom', 'G3')), (('Joshua', 'G2'), ('Tessa', 'G1')), 
(('Billie', 'G4'), ('Evan', 'G2')), (('Julian', 'G5'), ('Mia', 'G3')), 
(('Maddie', 'G1'), ('Claire', 'G3'))]
```

---

#### For Perm requirement

I probably know what to do now, but I want to say why your code doesn't work first.

`Perm` in your `randomMember(L)` which passed to `checkConstrainst(Perm,random(L))` has no relation with `D` in `random(L)`. You generate two different lists of numbers, using `D` to create random couples and do verification on it but then using `Perm` to return final result which did not verified.

The key point is using `Perm` to create random couples.

```
import random

members = [
    ('Tessa','G1'),('Evan','G2'),('Tom','G3'),('Mia','G3'),('Claire','G3'),
    ('Billie','G4'), ('Adrian','G2'),('Maddie','G1'),('Lewis','G1'),
    ('Tony','G2'),('Joyce','G1'),('Julian','G5'),('Joshua','G2'),('Warren','G3')
]

def check_constraint(perm,L):
    n = len(L)
    # use perm passed in to create random couples
    couples = [(L[i], L[perm[i]]) for i in range(n)]
    # check if they are in same group
    for pg1, pg2 in couples:
        if pg1[1] == pg2[1]:
            return False
    return True

def random_members(L):
    n = len(L)
    # create a list of size n with shuffled numbers equal to your permutation(n)
    perm = random.sample(range(n),n)
    # move random selection inside check_constraint() so just pass L here
    while check_constraint(perm,L) == False:
        perm = random.sample(range(n),n)
    couples = [(L[i], L[perm[i]]) for i in range(n)]
    return couples

print(random_members(members))
```

Output:

```
[(('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Tom', 'G3')), (('Evan', 'G2'), ('Maddie', 'G1')),
(('Tom', 'G3'), ('Tessa', 'G1')), (('Mia', 'G3'), ('Adrian', 'G2')),
(('Claire', 'G3'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Billie', 'G4'), ('Mia', 'G3')),
(('Adrian', 'G2'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Maddie', 'G1'), ('Joshua', 'G2')),
(('Lewis', 'G1'), ('Evan', 'G2')), (('Tony', 'G2'), ('Billie', 'G4')),
(('Joyce', 'G1'), ('Claire', 'G3')), (('Julian', 'G5'), ('Tony', 'G2')),
(('Joshua', 'G2'), ('Lewis', 'G1')), (('Warren', 'G3'), ('Joyce', 'G1'))]
```

I feel strange that if this your expected result. We will have 14 couples instead of 7 couples for 14 people. Some of them are duplicates like `(('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Tom', 'G3'))` and `(('Tom', 'G3'), ('Tessa', 'G1'))`, the remaining will be one to two relationship like `(('Evan', 'G2'), ('Maddie', 'G1'))` and `(('Lewis', 'G1'), ('Evan', 'G2'))`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... But, I have to use Perm in checkConstraint... Unfortunately...

Comment: I have edited the original post including `random(L)`.

Comment: And included what `random_member(L)` should look like (I have to complete).

Comment: @GeneralHarrigton but there is no checkConstraint() in your base code.

Comment: I have to use it in the while `randomMember(L)`

Comment: Looks like it works, thank you! I was really getting my mind too much in reality... I understood well with your comments, thanks again. I'll just have to go on, I go back to my pencil and paper !

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) method to get a list of all possible groups of 2, where the members of the group of 2 aren't from the same group:

```
from itertools import combinations

Members = [('Tessa','G1'),('Evan','G2'),('Tom','G3'),
           ('Mia','G3'),('Claire','G3'),('Billie','G4'),
           ('Adrian','G2'),('Maddie','G1'),('Lewis','G1'),
           ('Tony','G2'),('Joyce','G1'),('Julian','G5'),
           ('Joshua','G2'), ('Warren','G3')]

random = []
for a, b in combinations(Members, 2):
    if a[1] != b[1]:
        random.append((a, b))

print(random)
```

Output:

```
[(('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Evan', 'G2')), (('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Tom', 'G3')), (('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Mia', 'G3')), (('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Claire', 'G3')), (('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Billie', 'G4')), (('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Adrian', 'G2')), (('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Tony', 'G2')), (('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Joshua', 'G2')), (('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Evan', 'G2'), ('Tom', 'G3')), (('Evan', 'G2'), ('Mia', 'G3')), (('Evan', 'G2'), ('Claire', 'G3')), (('Evan', 'G2'), ('Billie', 'G4')), (('Evan', 'G2'), ('Maddie', 'G1')), (('Evan', 'G2'), ('Lewis', 'G1')), (('Evan', 'G2'), ('Joyce', 'G1')), (('Evan', 'G2'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Evan', 'G2'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Tom', 'G3'), ('Billie', 'G4')), (('Tom', 'G3'), ('Adrian', 'G2')), (('Tom', 'G3'), ('Maddie', 'G1')), (('Tom', 'G3'), ('Lewis', 'G1')), (('Tom', 'G3'), ('Tony', 'G2')), (('Tom', 'G3'), ('Joyce', 'G1')), (('Tom', 'G3'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Tom', 'G3'), ('Joshua', 'G2')), (('Mia', 'G3'), ('Billie', 'G4')), (('Mia', 'G3'), ('Adrian', 'G2')), (('Mia', 'G3'), ('Maddie', 'G1')), (('Mia', 'G3'), ('Lewis', 'G1')), (('Mia', 'G3'), ('Tony', 'G2')), (('Mia', 'G3'), ('Joyce', 'G1')), (('Mia', 'G3'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Mia', 'G3'), ('Joshua', 'G2')), (('Claire', 'G3'), ('Billie', 'G4')), (('Claire', 'G3'), ('Adrian', 'G2')), (('Claire', 'G3'), ('Maddie', 'G1')), (('Claire', 'G3'), ('Lewis', 'G1')), (('Claire', 'G3'), ('Tony', 'G2')), (('Claire', 'G3'), ('Joyce', 'G1')), (('Claire', 'G3'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Claire', 'G3'), ('Joshua', 'G2')), (('Billie', 'G4'), ('Adrian', 'G2')), (('Billie', 'G4'), ('Maddie', 'G1')), (('Billie', 'G4'), ('Lewis', 'G1')), (('Billie', 'G4'), ('Tony', 'G2')), (('Billie', 'G4'), ('Joyce', 'G1')), (('Billie', 'G4'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Billie', 'G4'), ('Joshua', 'G2')), (('Billie', 'G4'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Adrian', 'G2'), ('Maddie', 'G1')), (('Adrian', 'G2'), ('Lewis', 'G1')), (('Adrian', 'G2'), ('Joyce', 'G1')), (('Adrian', 'G2'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Adrian', 'G2'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Maddie', 'G1'), ('Tony', 'G2')), (('Maddie', 'G1'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Maddie', 'G1'), ('Joshua', 'G2')), (('Maddie', 'G1'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Lewis', 'G1'), ('Tony', 'G2')), (('Lewis', 'G1'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Lewis', 'G1'), ('Joshua', 'G2')), (('Lewis', 'G1'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Tony', 'G2'), ('Joyce', 'G1')), (('Tony', 'G2'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Tony', 'G2'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Joyce', 'G1'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Joyce', 'G1'), ('Joshua', 'G2')), (('Joyce', 'G1'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Julian', 'G5'), ('Joshua', 'G2')), (('Julian', 'G5'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Joshua', 'G2'), ('Warren', 'G3'))]
```

Comment: Thank you for this tip. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use this... I have to use randomMember with loops.

Comment: @GeneralHarrigton You mean no modules?

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like in this line

```
    while checkConstrainst(Perm,random(L)) == False:
```

you should not have `random(L)` just `L`. You are already randomizing your permutations

If you need to make 'L' random, either do it it right after you enter the function:

```
def randomMember(L):
    L = random(L)
    n = len(L)
```

or not have it at all, and call the function with randomized L:

```
...
randomMember(random(L))
```

The rationale being that in your original function you are checking permutations against a randomized `L` but then put couples together from the original `L`

Comment: What do you mean by "original function"? I've tried editing as you said but same result...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this. I have commented to give explanation of what I am doing in the program.

```
import random
Members = [('Tessa','G1'), ('Evan','G2'),  ('Tom','G3'),
           ('Mia','G3'),   ('Claire','G3'),('Billie','G4'),
           ('Adrian','G2'),('Maddie','G1'),('Lewis','G1'),
           ('Tony','G2'),  ('Joyce','G1'), ('Julian','G5'),
           ('Joshua','G2'),('Warren','G3')]

def randomMember(L):
    LCouples = []

    for memb1 in Members: #iterate thru each member of Members list

        #now create a list of all members that do not belong to same Group as memb1
        memb_others = [j for j in Members if j[1] != memb1[1]]

        #generate a random number between 0 and length of the new list of members
        r = random.randint(0,len(memb_others)-1)

        #pair them as couples and append to LCouples
        #the pairing will ensure no couple from same group are paired
        LCouples.append((memb1,memb_others[r]))

    #return the list of all randomly paired couples
    return LCouples

#print the full list of random members
print (randomMember(Members))
```

A few runs of this generated the following outputs:

Run 1:

```
[(('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Evan', 'G2'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Tom', 'G3'), ('Adrian', 'G2')), (('Mia', 'G3'), ('Tessa', 'G1')), (('Claire', 'G3'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Billie', 'G4'), ('Claire', 'G3')), (('Adrian', 'G2'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Maddie', 'G1'), ('Billie', 'G4')), (('Lewis', 'G1'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Tony', 'G2'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Joyce', 'G1'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Julian', 'G5'), ('Joshua', 'G2')), (('Joshua', 'G2'), ('Claire', 'G3')), (('Warren', 'G3'), ('Tessa', 'G1'))]
```

Run 2:

```
[(('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Adrian', 'G2')), (('Evan', 'G2'), ('Claire', 'G3')), (('Tom', 'G3'), ('Tessa', 'G1')), (('Mia', 'G3'), ('Evan', 'G2')), (('Claire', 'G3'), ('Maddie', 'G1')), (('Billie', 'G4'), ('Joshua', 'G2')), (('Adrian', 'G2'), ('Claire', 'G3')), (('Maddie', 'G1'), ('Billie', 'G4')), (('Lewis', 'G1'), ('Billie', 'G4')), (('Tony', 'G2'), ('Mia', 'G3')), (('Joyce', 'G1'), ('Mia', 'G3')), (('Julian', 'G5'), ('Joshua', 'G2')), (('Joshua', 'G2'), ('Tessa', 'G1')), (('Warren', 'G3'), ('Julian', 'G5'))]
```

Run 3:

```
[(('Tessa', 'G1'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Evan', 'G2'), ('Lewis', 'G1')), (('Tom', 'G3'), ('Lewis', 'G1')), (('Mia', 'G3'), ('Joyce', 'G1')), (('Claire', 'G3'), ('Julian', 'G5')), (('Billie', 'G4'), ('Lewis', 'G1')), (('Adrian', 'G2'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Maddie', 'G1'), ('Tony', 'G2')), (('Lewis', 'G1'), ('Mia', 'G3')), (('Tony', 'G2'), ('Maddie', 'G1')), (('Joyce', 'G1'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Julian', 'G5'), ('Billie', 'G4')), (('Joshua', 'G2'), ('Warren', 'G3')), (('Warren', 'G3'), ('Julian', 'G5'))]
```

Comment: I have to use checkConstrainst in the randomMember function... That is not easy!